# How to delete strings in a file without just overwriting the string

Tags: c, file

for example, i have a file that contains this:

```
hello
my
name
is
a-big-door
```

And i want to change "a-big-door" to a name. For example "peter". How do i do that without, just overwriting "a-big-door". Because when I try it this comes:

```
hello
my
name
is
peter-door
```

i want to delete the rest of the string "a-big-door", so this comes

```
hello
my
name
is
peter
```

this is what i tried

```
fseek(file, tell, SEEK_SET);

printf("Bitte geben sie ihren neuen Typ ein: ");
while ((getchar()) != '\n');
fgets(data.typ, sizeof data.typ, stdin);
NL(data.typ);

while ((getchar()) != '\n');
printf("Ueberschreibungsbestätigung(y/n)");
while((yon = getc(stdin)) == '\n');
if(yon == 'y')
{
    printf("Schreibe...");
    while(getc(file) != '\n')
{
    fprintf(file, " ");
}
    fprintf(file, "%s", data.typ);
    printf("erfolgreich Geschrieben!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to copy the contents of the file; write everything you want to keep to a temporary file, writing out the changed versions of things you want to modify, and not writing what you want to remove, and then rename it to the original.

Answer (score 0):

overwriting is a way of doing it you just need to continue to override with " "(BLANK) characters until the end of the row which is "\n"

Comment: this does not work

Comment: what do you mean doesn't work :) just debug your code.

Comment: i did it thats because im in stackoverflow